# Flask get an 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask

I was encountered an error when to run my app with python Flask framework. In the **Signin** form execute the ***validateLogin*** action was registered in ***app.py***. And I ensure that my store procedure is correct. Thank for your help!

In ***app.py***:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '12345'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'BucketList'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # All Good, let's call MySQL

            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.route('/showSignIn')
def showSignin():
    return render_template('signin.html')

@app.route('/validateLogin',methods=['POST'])
def validateLogin():
    try:
        _username = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # connect to mysql

        con = mysql.connect()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin',(_username))
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        if len(data) > 0:
            if check_password_hash(str(data[0][3]),_password):
                session['user'] = data[0][0]
                return redirect('/userHome')
            else:
                return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')
        else:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'Wrong Email address or Password.')


    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

@app.route('/userHome')
def userHome():
    return render_template('userHome.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

In ***signin.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Python Flask Bucket List App</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="../static/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" ><a href="/showSignUp">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Python Flask App</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Bucket List Sign In</h3>
        <form role="form" action="/validateLogin" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>

        <button id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
      </div>



      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in ***userHome.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Python Flask Bucket List App</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="../static/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Python Flask App</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome Home !!</h1>

        </div>


        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What error? Add the details of the error to your question. Try turning on debugging with `app.debug = True` prior to starting your app.

Comment: It was ran, but why check_password_hash function won't working as expect. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting a 500 internal server error suggests that an unhandled exception is being raised somewhere in your code. Look in the log file and turn on debugging (I am still not sure that you have done that!). With debugging enabled, the exception traceback will be nicely formatted and displayed in a web page.

Why isn't `check_password_hash()` working as you expect? What do you expect it to do? I suppose that you mean that it is not checking passwords correctly? Try printing out the values that are returned from the database, i.e. the value of `data`, in particular `data[0][3]`.

The `validateLogin()` function catches all exceptions and is supposed to display the exception in the `error.html` template. Is that page being rendered?